# How do I create an Excel Macro to output key/value pairs to file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

I have two columns as key/value pairs and want to export them to a file in the structure key=value (to create a properties file).

I tried this script:

```
Sub Properties()
Dim FileName As String, i As Integer, str As String

FileName = "C:\propstest.txt"

Open FileName For Output As #1

For i = 1 To 50
str = cells(i, 1) & "=" & cells(i, 2)
Write #1, str
Next i
Close #1

End Sub
```

It almost works but it prints to the file like

```
"key=value"
```

Is there a way to get rid of the quotation marks in the file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using WriteLine instead of Write should get rid of the quotation marks.

Comment: I ended up changing the Write to Print and it worked.  I think your way would have worked too, but I would have had to change more.